# Alexa skill's ( intrinsic features ) from web browser

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, aws-lex

Unable get intrinsic features of alexa from web app (bot)

already implemented voice bot using aws lex and added some custom intent using lambda function wanted to integrated existing  intrinsic features of alexa

ex : 
 1) Sport shop near me 
 2) movie theatre near me 
 3) movie theatres in LA

above cmd's working fine on alexa device but not getting similar response from browser